# Struts/JSP/SQL User or Administrator control (Tomcat)

Tags: jsp, tomcat, authentication, web, struts

So I have a mySQL database with a 'users' table which includes a username, password, and a boolean for admin or user.

I am using Struts and JSP to validate User/Password combinations, and my Java files are "Session Aware" (for what it's worth).

My question is: After I have validated the combination, and sent the user to a /secure/ namespace with interceptors checking for validation and all that... how can I let my webapp know if the user is an admin or not. This can be accessed through the SQL at any time, but I would like to divert the 2 to different jsp files (eg. user.jsp and admin.jsp) for different functionalists.

Thanks :)

P.S. A detailed explanation with an example would help me more than a conceptual how-to.

Comment: a simple solution is to add a Boolean filed in your user object which indicated if user is an Admin or not and based on this you can send user to different view. If i am correct you are using Struts2?

Comment: That's my question. HOW do I send them to a different view? should I use Action.INPUT and Action.SUCCESS for the two and then have the two pages in the strut?

Comment: you can send any string , check if your user object has say admin fag try than use like `return "admin"` else `return "user"`.and map these two in your mapping file to return to diferent view/jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, I did just that:

```
return "USER"; //or return "ADMIN";
```

and then in the struts I just substituted.